# Can not deploy my contract on ganache-cli using ETH mainnet fork

Tags: solidity, truffle, ganache, forks

I used ganache-cli in combination with my Infura key to fork ETH mainnet so I could use the Uniswap router in my development environment:

```
ganache-cli --fork https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/<mykeyhere>
```

This starts my local ganache blockchain without any errors. However when I deploy my contract with truffle:

```
truffle(development)> deploy
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Compiling your contracts...

> =========================== ✓ Fetching solc version list from solc-bin. Attempt #1 ✓ Fetching solc version list from solc-bin.
> Attempt #1
> > Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol
> > Compiling ./contracts/MollyCoin.sol
> > Artifacts written to /home/dogperson/Code/MollyCoin/build/contracts
> > Compiled successfully using:
>    - solc: 0.6.12+commit.27d51765.Emscripten.clang
> 
> UnhandledRejections detected Promise {   <rejected> CodedError: Given
> input "NaN" is not a number.
>       at /home/dogperson/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.9/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/webpack:/Ganache/chains/ethereum/ethereum/lib/src/forking/handlers/base-handler.js:174:23
>       at process.promise (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
>       at ProviderHandler.queueRequest (/home/dogperson/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.9/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/webpack:/Ganache/chains/ethereum/ethereum/lib/src/forking/handlers/base-handler.js:178:36)
>       at ProviderHandler.request (/home/dogperson/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.9/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/webpack:/Ganache/chains/ethereum/ethereum/lib/src/forking/handlers/provider-handler.js:58:9)
>       at earliestBlock (/home/dogperson/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.9/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/webpack:/Ganache/chains/ethereum/ethereum/lib/src/forking/persistent-cache/helpers.js:149:5)
>       at previousClosestAncestor (/home/dogperson/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.9/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/webpack:/Ganache/chains/ethereum/ethereum/lib/src/forking/persistent-cache/helpers.js:77:19)
>       at PersistentCache.cache [as initialize] (/home/dogperson/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.9/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/webpack:/Ganache/chains/ethereum/ethereum/lib/src/forking/persistent-cache/persistent-cache.js:142:47)
>       at Fork.cache [as initCache] (/home/dogperson/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.9/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/webpack:/Ganache/chains/ethereum/ethereum/lib/src/forking/fork.js:209:21)
>       at Fork.fallback [as initialize] (/home/dogperson/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.9/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/webpack:/Ganache/chains/ethereum/ethereum/lib/src/forking/fork.js:206:13)
>       at Blockchain.async [as initialize] (/home/dogperson/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.9/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/webpack:/Ganache/chains/ethereum/ethereum/lib/src/blockchain.js:629:22)
>       at EthereumProvider.async [as initialize] (/home/dogperson/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.9/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/webpack:/Ganache/chains/ethereum/ethereum/lib/src/provider.js:195:5)
>       at Connector.connect (/home/dogperson/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.9/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/webpack:/Ganache/chains/ethereum/ethereum/lib/src/connector.js:49:5)
> {
>     code: -32000   } } CodedError: Given input "NaN" is not a number.
>     at /home/dogperson/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.9/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/webpack:/Ganache/chains/ethereum/ethereum/lib/src/forking/handlers/base-handler.js:174:23
>     at process.promise (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
>     at ProviderHandler.queueRequest (/home/dogperson/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.9/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/webpack:/Ganache/chains/ethereum/ethereum/lib/src/forking/handlers/base-handler.js:178:36)
>     at ProviderHandler.request (/home/dogperson/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.9/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/webpack:/Ganache/chains/ethereum/ethereum/lib/src/forking/handlers/provider-handler.js:58:9)
>     at earliestBlock (/home/dogperson/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.9/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/webpack:/Ganache/chains/ethereum/ethereum/lib/src/forking/persistent-cache/helpers.js
```

Comment: What are you doing in the migration scripts?

Comment: Did you find any idea to solve it ?